# Geometry Nodes messes up Vector Displacement

Tags: modeling, materials, geometry-nodes, procedural

Please help me check out the Maths of these nodes.

I’m combining the Shader Nodes and Geometry Nodes to create something.
This “Multiple Balls” object is using Geometry Nodes to assign “Individual Ball” object as instances on it.

[image]

What I want to achieve is,
[image]
wherever I slide the red colored node to, the instances get spiked up and that part is colored darker blue, which exactly is happening with the desired version on the right (it is done without Geometry Nodes, it’s just 5 boxes being copypasted manually). And the failed version on the left fails to display what I want and it uses Geometry Nodes, so I suspect that the problem comes from Geometry Nodes instead of Shader Nodes.

Blender file: https://blenderartists.org/uploads/short-url/webCSUCDF129U0B5WutAfQqjnEj.blend

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's looking like linked objects can't have different vertex positions, since they have shared mesh data. So that you have to realize instances.

Then enable Realize instances, I save center of instances in points domain:

[image: (can't upload picture, will try later)]

Then to get coordinates, just subtract saved value from object coordinates:

[image: (can't upload picture, will try later)]

Here is the result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Really appreciate your help!
May I ask what happened to your uploaded picture? The pictures don't show up but there's a message saying that "(can't upload picture, will try later)"?

Comment: @IanAmbrose it didn't load yesterday, so I wrote this message

Comment: Hi, sorry for bothering you, could you please work with my file again, but this time, you change absolutely nothing but add new necessary stuff that can help me achieve my purpose. Would that be possible? You removed a few important nodes of mine in Shader Nodes which Mathematically confuses me.